# CSS: How to remove borders on Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm working with the Brunch Pro theme for Wordpress and am seeing a 1px border under each of my entires on the homepage, as well as below each widget in the sidebar. I would like to get rid of those.

You can see my site [here](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/). I've attempted to edit these lines in the stylesheet but have gotten no result:

```css
.featured-content .entry {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .widget {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

There must be something I don't understand. This theme loads all of my posts into a widget area, which is not something I'm used to. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: I don't see the borders. Can you post a screenshot? :) Edit: I see the borders below the widgets not the entries though.

Comment: hmm I don't see a way to post a screenshot here :(

Comment: Use the 6th icon in the editor.

Comment: Have you tried it in /wp-content/themes/brunch-pro/style.css @ line 1111?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `style.css` file still appears to show `border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;`, are you sure the changes have been committed?

You may be better off just adding the following in the **Appearance** > **Customizer** > **Additional CSS** section of your site:

```
.sidebar .widget,
.featured-content .entry {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's seems to be saving my changes when I go into the editor to change the code but I'll give that a shot right now.

Comment: I can see the `style.css` file has a missing line where the border declaration was for `.featured-content .entry {`, (line 1112) but it doesn't appear the same change has been made to `sidebar .widget {` (line 1859). Though as a note, you should be careful using the Appearance Editor (especially when editing PHP files, not so much CSS files). Typically for "per site" CSS changes, you're better off with a custom stylesheet or using the customizer anyways.

Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.css change

```
.featured-content .entry {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .widget {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

to

```
.featured-content .entry {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .widget {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: But she said she had edited those. It can be a cache issue.

Comment: yep, I already did that. I checked multiple browsers and it still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `border: none;`

If that's overwritten by WordPress do it like this: `border: none !important;`

Comment: hmm that still doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: You should avoid the use of frivolous `!important;` declarations. The selectors that are causing the issue aren't specific enough to warrant that, and WP itself isn't touching them, just the two selectors in the `style.css` file.

Comment: euhm, she said each widget and each entry so should be specific enough. And yes I agree, you better avoid using `!important` but sometimes there's not really any other solution.